Modulus `%%` giving unexpected result for `3.1 %% 0.1`. Is this expected?
I'm using the base modulus (%%) operator, and just struggling to understand the following behaviour. My understanding is that %% returns the remainder after dividing 2 numbers. So eg:
5 %% 2
# [1] 1

6 %% 2
# [1] 0

Since after dividing 5 by 2 the remainder is 1, and after dividing 6 by 2 the remainder is 0. It also works with decimals, e.g.:
3.2 %% 0.1
# [1] 0

I also realise that floating point issues might come up in some cases, e.g.:
12345.2 %% 0.1
# [1] 4.263256e-14

I assume that's because the floating point of 12345.2 is actually 12345.2000000000000042632... No issue there.
Where I'm getting confused is here:
3.1 %% 0.1
# [1] 0.1

Why is there 0.1 remainder in the above? I was assuming the result would be 0 (or very close to zero if there's a floating point issue). Am I missing something?
I expected any value with 1 or fewer decimal points of precision would give 0, but there are lots of results that seem inconsistent with that (note I'm rounding the output just to avoid the "e-14" results like above):
data.frame(num = seq.int(3, 5, 0.1)) |>
  dplyr::mutate(result = round(num %% 0.1, 4))
#    num result
# 1  3.0    0.1
# 2  3.1    0.1
# 3  3.2    0.0
# 4  3.3    0.1
# 5  3.4    0.1
# 6  3.5    0.1
# 7  3.6    0.1
# 8  3.7    0.1
# 9  3.8    0.1
# 10 3.9    0.1
# 11 4.0    0.1
# 12 4.1    0.1
# 13 4.2    0.1
# 14 4.3    0.1
# 15 4.4    0.0
# 16 4.5    0.1
# 17 4.6    0.1
# 18 4.7    0.1
# 19 4.8    0.1
# 20 4.9    0.0
# 21 5.0    0.1

If I multiply all values (both numbers and the modulo operator) by 10, I get the behaviour I expect:
data.frame(num = seq.int(30, 50, 1)) |>
  dplyr::mutate(result = round(num %% 1, 4))
#    num result
# 1   30      0
# 2   31      0
# 3   32      0
# 4   33      0
# 5   34      0
# 6   35      0
# 7   36      0
# 8   37      0
# 9   38      0
# 10  39      0
# 11  40      0
# 12  41      0
# 13  42      0
# 14  43      0
# 15  44      0
# 16  45      0
# 17  46      0
# 18  47      0
# 19  48      0
# 20  49      0
# 21  50      0

Worth noting that what I'm seeing is consistent in Python too. This shows the same behaviour:
import math
[math.fmod(x/10.0, 0.1) for x in range(30, 50, 1)]

Is there something I'm missing?

See help("%%"), which addresses this.

3.1 %% print(0.1, digits=19)

@Roland do you mean here? "... results are subject to representation error... the answer to 1 %/% 0.2 should be 4 but most platforms give 5."

@Edward I think I see what you mean. 0.1 is slightly larger that it seems, so fewer "fit in" to 3.1 than you'd think. In which case, the remainder is really close (but slightly smaller) than 0.1. Is that accurate?

Yes, ............

Basically this - Why are these numbers not equal?

python: print(f'{ 0.1 :.55f}') gives 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 (and this is why popular 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 gives False)

Thank you all for the help. I realise the floating point issue is well established, just didn't see how it applied here (since the "error" seems to be 0.1 which is too big to be from floating point in this case). It makes more sense to me now though.

I think you have found out where the issue comes from, and I believe you have your own ways to circumvent it. Below is just a possible workaround that may interest you.

Probably you can play some preprocessing tricks before %% (see in f2(x,y))
f1 <- \(x, y) x %% y

f2 <- \(x, y)  ((x / y) %% 1L) * y

and you can see the following output examples

x<- 1.3; y <- 0.1

> f1(x, y)
[1] 0.1

> f2(x, y)
[1] 0


x <- 1.56; y <- 0.27

> f1(x, y)
[1] 0.21

> f2(x, y)
[1] 0.21


x <- -0.9; y <- 0.1

> f1(x, y)
[1] 2.775558e-17

> f2(x, y)
[1] 0


Thank you @ThomasIsCoding. This is helpful, not to mention an interesting logical work-around!

Thanks to those in the comments, I can now see how this is caused by floating point (I'll shorten to FP) precision, so thought I'd add an answer in case it's useful to anyone else. I had initially thought that this couldn't be a FP issue because the result being returned is 0.1 instead of the expected 0, which is a far bigger difference than I'm used to seeing for a FP error (unless the error has been multiplied somehow, which is not the case here).
To explain why this happens, take the example of 0.9 %% 0.1, which is an example where the output is not the expected 0.
0.9 %% 0.1
# [1] 0.1

If we look at both numbers closely we can see where FP precision comes in:
print(0.9, digits = 22)
# [1] 0.9000000000000000222045

print(0.1, digits = 22)
# [1] 0.1000000000000000055511

Note the digits line up pretty nicely, so we can see that 0.9 has an extra 222045e-22, and 0.1 has an extra 55511e-22 thanks to FP.
We expect 0.1 to multiply 9 times cleanly into 0.9 (hence the expected 0 result to the %% function). Notice that 9 times 0.1 comes out slightly larger than 0.9, which we can see by multiplying that e-22 (the FP extra bit) part out:
55511 * 9
# 499599

Note that's larger than the 222045 FP "extra bit" that 0.9 got. Therefore, when R "tries" to multiply 0.1 out 9 times, it doesn't quite fit into 0.9. So it has to assume that the most times 0.1 can be multiplied before going past 0.9 is 8 (notably 0.9 %/% 0.1 gives 8), which leaves a teeny-tiny bit less than 0.1 left over.
print(0.9 %% 0.1, digits = 22)
# [1] 0.09999999999999997779554

Worth noting that if 9 times the FP representation of 0.1 were slightly smaller than the FP of 0.9 instead of larger, then the remainder would be really close to 0 (maybe in the 1e-15 range ish), and R would return 0.
As with any FP issue, I hate to say "oh that's fine then". Unfortunately (at least IMO) we have to think of this as a limitation of the way computers perform mathematical calculations. As long as we're using floating point arithmetic, we need to accept the fact that issues like this will crop up. Having seen FP issues a fair bit before I thought I could spot them when I saw them. This one got me, and I'm sure it won't be the last time that happens.
Even looking into this issue, I come across things like the below, which continue to completely do my head in:
# get 0.7 in a round-about way
x <- seq.int(0, 0.8, 0.1)[8]
x
# [1] 0.7

# this gives very close to 0
x %% 0.1
# [1] 2.775558e-17

# get what appears to be the same number in a similar but different way
x <- seq.int(0.5, 0.8, 0.1)[3]
x
# [1] 0.7

# which gives a different result
x %% 0.1
# [1] 0.1

# that's the same result as defining 0.7 directly
0.7 %% 0.1
# [1] 0.1

